# integrating breeze and sails/waterline

Tags: sails.js, breeze, waterline

I have what amounts to the start of a **Node/Express** application which is using breeze to do its CRUD operations. Currently I am using Node/Sequelize -> Postgres. Being new to NodeJS, I just recently came across SailJS. It looks cool and I would like to consider using for my app. However, I am very unclear on how Breeze would integrate with Sails/Waterline.

Specifically, breeze provides a breeze-sequelize adapter, then it communicates to sequelize in redderick that sequelize understands.

I wonder how difficult it would be to either:

1. Have breeze communicate to waterline just as it does to sequelize
2. Use sails with sails with sequlize instead waterline

I have come across posts where this subject has been touched upon but I haven't been able to find an in-depth post covering this issue.

Thanks in advance.

edit - example of breeze in action (bear in mind, this is doctored for simplicity):

**Client:**

```
    (function(angular) {
        'use strict';

        angular.module('dataAccess')
                    .factory('Repository', ['breeze', '$rootScope', 'ListHelper', factory]);

        function factory(breeze, $rootScope) {
            return function (entityManagerProvider, resourceName) {

                this.getByKey = getByKey;
                this.buildAll = buildAll;
                this.all = all;
                this.buildQuery = buildQuery;
                this.query = query;
                this.executeQuery = executeQuery;
                this.findInCache = findInCache;
                var test = getMetastore();
                var entityTypeName = getMetastore().getEntityTypeNameForResourceName(resourceName);
                var entityType = getMetastore().getEntityType(entityTypeName);

                //activate();

                ////////

                function activate () {
                    if (entityTypeName) {
                        //getMetastore().setEntityTypeForResourceName(resourceName, entityTypeName);
                    }
                }

                function buildAll () {
                    return breeze.EntityQuery
                        .from(resourceName);
                }

                function all (options) {
                    return executeQuery(this.buildAll(), options || {});
                }

                function query (predicate, options) {
                    return executeQuery(this.buildQuery(predicate), options || {});
                }

                function buildQuery (predicate) {
                    return predicate ? this.buildAll().where(predicate) : this.buildAll();
                }

                function executeQuery(query, options) {
                    return entityManagerProvider.manager()
                        .executeQuery(query.using(options && options.fetchStrategy ? options.fetchStrategy : breeze.FetchStrategy.FromServer));
                }

                function getMetastore() {
                    return manager().metadataStore;
                }

                function

 manager() {
                return entityManagerProvider.manager();
            }
        };
    }

})(window.angular);
```

**Server:**

```
    var fs = require('fs'),
        breezeSequelize = require('breeze-sequelize'),
        config = require('./config');

    var SequelizeManager = breezeSequelize.SequelizeManager;
    var SequelizeQuery = breezeSequelize.SequelizeQuery;
    var SequelizeSaveHandler = breezeSequelize.SequelizeSaveHandler;

    var manager = createSequelizeManager();

    var breeze = breezeSequelize.breeze;

    function createSequelizeManager() {
        var metadata = readMetadata();
        var sm = new SequelizeManager(config.db.dbConfig, config.db.options);
        sm.importMetadata(metadata);
        return sm;
    }

    function readMetadata() {
        var filename = "MetaData.json";
        if (!fs.existsSync(filename)) {
            throw new Error("Unable to locate file: " + filename);
        }
        return fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
    }

//controller method, handles all breeze get requests
        function get (req, res, next) {
            var resourceName = req.params.entity;
            var entityQuery = entityQuery.fromUrl(req.url, resourceName);
            executeEntityQuery(entityQuery)
                .then(function (r) {
                    res.json(r);
            }).catch(next);
        }

    function executeEntityQuery(entityQuery) {
        var query = new SequelizeQuery(manager, entityQuery);
        return query.execute();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with breeze, however, if you provide an example CRUD operation you'd like to perform I can step you through it in Sails.  You can generate a JSON CRUD API in sails by simply typing $ sails generate api [api name].

Comment: @JohnGalt The issue is that breeze automates all the CRUD. I will edit the OP to show an example of breeze in action.